# How to Configure an Object Data Source to execute code to determine a method parameter

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, objectdatasource

I have a GridView bound to an ObjectDataSource whos SELECT operation is bound to Method on a WebService.

The WebService method takes 2 parameters :

```
GetJurUsersCollection(String currentUserName, String userNameSearchPattern), returns JurUser[]
```

How can I configure the ObjectDataSource to execute the required code to determine the value to supply for parameter 1 :

```
GetCurrentUserName();
```

Many thanks.